# $c$ is a complex number that satisyfing $(c+\frac{1}{c}+1)(c+\frac{1}{c}) = 1$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $c$ is complex-number satisfying :

$(c+\frac{1}{c}+1)(c+\frac{1}{c}) = 1$

So, how could i get
$(3c^{100}+\frac{2}{c^{100}}+1)(c^{100}+\frac{2}{c^{100}}+3)$ ?

Comment: Please formulate it as a question rather than a statement. Though most people probably understand what you are asking, it may not be obvious to some non-native speakers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

On simplification, $c^4+c^3+c^2+c+1=0$

Clearly,  $c\ne1$

Multiply either sides the $(c-1),$ we get $c^5-1=(c-1)\cdot0=0$

$\implies c^5=1\implies c^{100}=(c^5)^{20}=1$

Comment: Thank you for that solution :)

Comment: @freeze, my pleasure